# LINQ OrderBy not working on Dictionary Key

Tags: c#, linq

seems ok to me but my list still isn't ordered by my key.

```
    var tagNamesAndRoutes = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string name in tagNames)
    {
        tagNamesAndRoutes.Add(name, routeConstant);
    }
```

Example of dictionary values:

```
Key       Value
"NUnit"     "/Category"
"WCF"       "/Category"
"ReSharper" "/Category"
```

and so on.

I tried to sort it via typical LINQ:

```
tagNamesAndRoutes.OrderBy(c => c.Key);
```

but it's not sorted after the fact.

Comment: Did you try SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>?

Comment: Were you using the return value?  OrderBy has no side effect. e.g. var sortedTagNamesAndRoutes = tagNamesAndRoutes.OrderBy(c => c.Key);

Comment: Tested your code and it seems to work fine. You need to use what `OrderBy` returns. It doesn`t make changes to the original dictionary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ - dynamic orderby clause does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409878/linq-dynamic-orderby-clause-does-not-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OrderBy` actually returns you the ordered collection. Try this:

```
var orderedTagNamesAndRoutes = tagNamesAndRoutes.OrderBy(c => c.Key);
```

Then use `orderedTagNamesAndRoutes`.

If you want your dictionary to be sorted itself, you can use `SortedDictionary`.
Try:

```
var tagNamesAndRoutes = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
```

You do not need to call `OrderBy` in this case. The dictionary is always sorted by the key.

Comment: the first changes it to an Enumerable so I'd have to cast it back to a dictionary...I'd rather prevent a cast, so probably second is better unless anyone knows of any performance issues with SortedDictionary..but preventing casting is far more performant.

Comment: @WeDoTDD - You wouldn't be doing a "cast" to get it back. You'd need to build a new dictionary from the ordered enumerable.

Answer (score 3):

**OrderBy** returns an **IOrderedEnumerable** which you can iterate in the sorted order and doesn't modify the actual dictionary.

So you need to do something like

```
var sorted = tagNamesAndRoutes.OrderBy(c => c.Key);
foreach (string name in sorted) {
    ...
}
```

The Dictionary type itself has no notion of order for its keys. You can use SortedDictionary if you always want the keys sorted.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: yea I guess I don't get the OrderBy then still